# Current Directory Window Title

Tags: vim, macvim

is there a way to expose the current working directory as perhaps the window title in MacVim?

My use case is I have a few MacVim windows open, each rooted at a particular directory for a section of my project, or individual projects.  So it would be really useful to be able to identify them by the folder they're open in.

Cheers,
rod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:set titlestring=YOURTITLEHERE` changes the title of the "window". There is an automatic example at `:help titlestring`.

Answer (score 3):

set titlestring+=\ pwd:\ %{substitute(getcwd(),\ $HOME,\ '~',\ '')}

backslash and space are only to insert a space into the titlestring.
pwd: (and another escaped space) are only a label.
%{ . . . } evaluates the bracket contents dynamically.
%{getcwd()} is the key to get the current directory.
This also shortens $HOME to ~ before adding it to titlestring.

More vim ideas at https://ciaranm.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/my-vimrc/